# Why is the dimension of $k$-Tensors that are antisymmetric $\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove it but so far I can only write the antisymmetric tensor using the basis for all $k$-tensors. Can you please help me?

Let $V$ be a vector space and $\{e_1, ...,e_n \}$ it's basis

If $v \in V , v=\sum_{i=0}^nλ_ie_i$ and $φ_i(v)=λ_i$ then $ \{φ_i\} , i=1,...,n$ is the basis of the dual $V^*$

I have shown that if $T$ is a $k$-tensor ($k<n$) and if $I=\{i_1,...i_k\} \in\{1,...,n\}^k$ is a $k$-combination of $\{1,...,n\}$, then $\{φ_I=φ_{i_1}\otimes ... \otimes φ_{i_k} \}$, $I \in\{1,...,n\}^k$ is the basis for all $k$-tensors

Meaning that $T=\sum T_Iφ_I$ where $Τ_I=T(e_{i_1},...e_{i_k})$ for all $I \in\{1,...,n\}^k$

Now if $w$ is an antisymmetric tensor then $w=\sum w_Iφ_I \Rightarrow ALT(w)=w=\sum w_IALT(φ_I) \Rightarrow $

$w=\sum w_IALT(φ_{i_1}\otimes ... \otimes φ_{i_k}) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum w_Iφ_{i_1}\land ... \land φ_{i_k} $

And that's as far as I can go.

I think I got it! We know that $w\landθ=-θ \land w$ Therefore if there are $i_λ,i_j \in I=\{i_1,...,i_k\} $ so that $i_λ=i_j$ then $φ_I=φ_{i_1}\land ... \land φ_{i_k}=0$ because $w\land w=-w \land w$ and also if $I,J$ have the same elements but in different order then $φ_I+φ_J$ equals either $0$ or $2φ_I$

So the $I$s in $\frac{1}{k!}\sum w_Iφ_I $ can be $\binom{n}{k}$ in total

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Could you please include some more details on what you've been able to do so far?

Comment: I will try. We are using some weird notation though. I hope it will not add to the confusion.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. I'll check it tomorrow and if I'm correct I'll post it!